# MySql SUM() function

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use MySql SUM() function inside another MySql SUM() function ??

Like below

```
$query="SELECT SUM(Table1.Column1+SUM(Table2.Column2+Table2.Column3)) 
        from Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.table1_id 
        WHERE Table1.Column2='Test'";
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(foo) + SUM(bar) as foobar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Column1 + Table2.Column2 + Table2.Column3) ...
```

Or use `SUM()` on each field:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Column1) + SUM(Table2.Column2) + SUM(Table2.Column3) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From basic math a + b + c = a + (b + c)

So just use one sum. It will be equivalent with what you are doing there ..